# Nokia-2.2 USB drivers for use with Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, nokia

Can anyone point me to a reliable source for downloading OEM USB drivers for Nokia 2.2, which is a phone I am using to learn android development?

Android's own page for downloading OEM drivers ( [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/oem-usb.html#Drivers) ) includes most manufacturers but not Nokia. Could not find anything on Nokia's own site either. I also checked out previously asked questions on stackoverflow but they are either too dated (links don't work, etc.) or they are about different phones, or are too complex/unclear for me to follow. I also trying doing a Google search for Nokia USB drivers but the sites seem too dodgy to try out - are any of these safe to use?

In trying to make the phone work with Android studio, I have enabled USB debugging and checked that files can be transferred. When i run "Troubleshoot device connections" in Android Studio, it can apparently detect my Nokia phone, but lists it among "USB device(s) not recognized as Android devices."

I am using Android Studio 3.6.3 on a 32-bit Windows 8 machine. Any help or workaround will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use universal adb drivers -- https://adb.clockworkmod.com/

Comment: Thanks a lot, user13531614. I got a warning while installing the drivers. Are these safe to use?